# Imagemagick 6.9.11-60 - how to remove blue background

Tags: debian, graphics, imagemagick

Imagemagick 6.9.11-60 on Debian. The images of b/w documents taken near the window all have the blue background: how to eliminate that background? (the docs are b/w)

I can't post the full pictures due to proprietary, but most pictures have blue background, sample:

[image]

Comment: not quite sure what you mean, honestly. Can you add an example image to your question and explain what you want to change?

Comment: I can't post the full pictures due to proprietary, but most documents pictures have blue background, sample [here](https://i.postimg.cc/8zc61qxT/sample.jpg). I want fiter out that background, also reduce pictures size, in one command.

Comment: OK, added the image to your question (next time, generally, please add info to questions, not just comments). What I'm still wondering about is the meaning of the verb "to filter" in your parlance. In my world, filtering out a color would make all areas with that color black, and not change image sizes at all.

Comment: Yes, I meant to remove blue background.

Comment: not better, still not clear what "remove" means.

Comment: try `convert input.png -fuzz 10% -fill white -opaque '#2C98E0' output.png` see how it works...